# bash: executing su -c breaks $@

Tags: bash, shell-script, su

> Bash version: GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

This works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /app/add_container_host.py $@
```

But I need to run it as a certain user, so I've changed it to:

```
#!/bin/bash
su -c '/usr/local/bin/python2.7 /app/add_container_host.py $@' $USER
```

and the Python script is no longer getting the arguments.

I've tried changing the single-quote to double quote and that's supplying the `$@` to `su -c` itself, not to the Python script.

Is there a way to pass `$@` to the python script while running it as `su -c`?

Comment: Try changing those single tick quotes to double quotes. Single's inhibit the variables inside them from being expanded.

Comment: @slm i did and su is getting the arguments, instead of the python script. "su: unrecognized option '--rh6'" the --rh6 option should be going to python script, not su

Comment: What's the call to this script look like?

Comment: Show (don't describe) what you did.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to safely pass `$@`: `su user -c 'command "$@"' -- argv0 "$@"`. (you should omit the `--` on non-linux systems). See the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/479645/308316) for an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is the quotes you're using. You need to use double quotes so that the variables within, `$@`, can be expanded, otherwise they'll remain literals and never get expanded.

#### Here's an example

```
$ cat runme.bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "run with double quotes"
su -c "echo $@" user1

echo "run with single quotes"
su -c 'echo $@' user1

$ ./runme.bash "a b c"
run with double quotes
a b c
run with single quotes

$
```

You also have to pass the list of arguments in as a quoted list, otherwise the `su -c ...` command gets confused and starts trying to parse the 2nd argument as the user that you want to `su` as.

#### Another example

```
$ ./runme.bash a b c
run with double quotes
su: user b does not exist
run with single quotes

$
```

#### Debugging tip

If you want to see what the script is actually doing you can run it with the `-x` switch to `bash`.

*bare arguments*

```
$ bash -x ./runme.bash a b c
+ echo 'run with double quotes'
run with double quotes
+ su -c 'echo a' b c user1
su: user b does not exist
+ echo 'run with single quotes'
run with single quotes
+ su -c 'echo $@' user1

$
```

*quoted arguments*

```
$ bash -x ./runme.bash "a b c"
+ echo 'run with double quotes'
run with double quotes
+ su -c 'echo a b c' user1
a b c
+ echo 'run with single quotes'
run with single quotes
+ su -c 'echo $@' user1

$
```

Comment: thank you i didnt pass in the arguments as a quoted list so su -c was trying to parse the 2nd one as its own argument

Comment: Yeah the passing of args can be pretty tricky, glad this helped.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know Linux `su` was so different from the BSD `su`.  On BSD you would just do `su username -c 'command with args using "$@"' su-sh "$@"`

Comment: @Kusalananda - yes it's very peculiar. I don't run into a lot of scenarios where I ever have to personally use it, I mainly know about it b/c of the Q&A I see here 8-).  I try to do everything via `sudo -u` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider passing the shell positional parameters to the `su` command as arguments, rather than relying on having them correctly expanded in the `-c` argument string.

For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

su testuser -c 'for arg; do echo "$0 ($(whoami)): $arg"; done' -- su "$@"
```

then

```
$ ./suscript foo "bar baz"
Password: 
su (testuser): foo
su (testuser): bar baz
```

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulating the command inside a here-doc block may help you.

```
#!/bin/sh

su testuser -s /bin/sh <<EOF
 add_container_host.py "$@"
EOF
```

You can try like below as well

```
su testuser -c 'add_container_host.py "$@"' -- argv0 "$@"
```

Apart from it [su-exec](https://github.com/ncopa/su-exec) is also a nice alternative.

Comment: May I know the reason behind negative impression on this anser ? Does this answer have any flaw ?